# linum auto-activation in .emacs fails

Tags: emacs

I added the following lines to my .emacs.d/init.el
to auto-activate linum at startup:

```
(require 'linum)
(global-linum-mode 1)
(setq linum-format “%d “)
```

But no way, i still have to manually `M-x linum-mode`
to make it display line numbers in my C buffers (and all other buffers).
Any idea?

(GNU Emacs 23.2.1, modified by Debian)

Comment: `~/.emacs/init.el` is not loaded automatically, do you mean `~/.emacs.d/init.el`? According to http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init it will also not automatically load `~/.emacs.d/init.el` if you have a `~/.emacs` file

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, I meant .emacs.d/init.el, and I have no  directory of file .emacs...

Comment: Is this copied verbatim from your init.el? Your double quotes are wrong, use `"`, not `“`. Then it works for me (at least from my `~/.emacs` file).

Comment: actually it happens there were a syntax error higher in my init.el so the linum specific commands were skipped. Thanks for your help anyway! should i delete my question?